# Spark from_avro function with schema registry support

Tags: apache-spark, confluent-schema-registry, spark-avro

I am trying to use confluent schema reigstry with sparks `from_avro` function as per this [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/schema-registry-integration/index.html#avro-data-and-schema-registry.html).

I have the below imports:

```
"io.confluent" % "kafka-schema-registry-client" % "5.4.1",
"io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "5.4.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % "2.4.5",
```

However, I only see the below method signature available.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._
from_avro(data: Column, jsonFormatSchema : String)
```

and not the one I expect with schema registry support.

```
from_avro($"value", "topic-value", schemaRegistryAddr)
```

Am I missing something? I understood that `2.4.5` is the latest stable version for `spark-avro`, but it does not seem to support the same signature mentioned in the [databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html#example-with-schema-registry). Inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below feature is not available in `spark 2.4.5` as of now.

```
from_avro($"value", "topic-value", schemaRegistryAddr)
```

It is only available in Databricks environment or Databricks notebook.

Comment: why would it not be available outside of Databricks?